# Logging class with static members

Tags: java, design-patterns, logging

I created a class that roughly looks like this.

```
public class CodingLogger {
    private static StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    public static void println(Object o) {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(o));
        buffer.append(String.valueOf(o) + LINE_SEPARATOR);
    }
}
```

Is there a specific name for this kind of class (accessible everywhere, without instance)? Or this is typical Utility pattern?

Comment: The pattern name would be [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) - or a form of it.

Comment: If you want an honest answer, the name I would give it is... "Bad idea". You could consider it a singleton, as Thomas mentioned, but not quite since there isn't really an instance of the class itself.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz yeah it's sort of a singleton (at least some people implement it that way) but I really like the name "Bad-Idea" pattern  - the only proplem with that being that there are so many of them ;)

Comment: Please use StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer as it was replaced more than ten years ago.

Comment: To expand a little on why this is considered a bad idea: think about what you'd have to do if you called that method in a lot of places and then need to use multiple buffers - you'd have to change all those places or at least a lot of them. That's just one of the problems with this.

Comment: @Thomas - Personally, I try to avoid the Singleton pattern whenever possible and this isn't even a "real" singleton, just some static state stinking around somewhere. Perhaps it has an Antipattern name, but if so, I don't know it.

Comment: I agree, that is bad idea, so I will change it to Context Singleton (one instance per context, that is JRules Context in IBM Execution server) cos without instance multiple contexts use same Log concurrently. @Thomas But if not that problem with concurrency, I don't understand what is bad in Singleton or in this class, that have no instance if only task is to save whatever is written in it.

Comment: Looks like you're reinventing a wheel. There are several logging libraries available (my favorite is LogBack). Your 'solution' introduces a global state, i. e. all sorts of multithreading issues (in general, not in your case since StringBuffer is thread-safe) and many hours of debugging in an attempt to figure out 'what sequence of events could cause this specific contents of my buffer?')

Comment: @kirill-gamazkov dont know how StringBuffer is safe, but in my case, when i send 100 invoices to code in two threads, logs got messed up. I described case in comment before

Comment: StringBuffer is synchronized and that's why it's thread-safe, but what you are doing is not .. what are you trying to achieve? do you want to print the contents of the StringBuffer at the end? cause if what you print in the system.out.println are your logs, then that's the problem. Firstly, I don't see the use of the StringBuffer. Secondly, The java docs never said that the system.out.println method is synchronized or thread-safe so you shouldn't assume that .. and as @kirill-gamazkov said, don't reinvent the wheel .. use log4j or logback, simple and guaranteed with lots of options

Answer (score 0):

There's no name for such a class.

This is not the Singleton, because there is no problem with creating an instance of the class.

You should ask yourself why you need such a class? What is the purpose? Why it is static? Because it is easier to use without injection? If so, you are doing nothing more, but hidding dependencies.
You need to know the motivations and double check whether the reasons are good.

Remember that you should write **Object**-Orieted Code. If there is no instance of the class you cannot name it Object-Oriented.